# Characters are not being picked up by <KeyPress unless function is pressed at the same time, but all non-characters are picked up fine

Tags: python, tkinter

While it works fine on windows, on mac the keys w, a, s and d that I've been trying to use to make a character move are not picked up by

I have no idea how to fix the error, as this is my first week with python. I can't think of anything to try.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=100, height=100)
keylist = []
def press(event):
    if event.keysym not in keylist:
        keylist.append(event.keysym)
def release(event):
    if event.keysym in keylist:
        keylist.remove(event.keysym)
def test():
    print(keylist)
    window.after(200, test)
test()
canvas.bind("<KeyPress>", press)
canvas.bind("<KeyRelease>", release)
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.pack()
window.mainloop
```

I expected the console to output [] if there is no result (which did happen), but I also expected it to output ['q'] when I press/hold q, which did not happen, or for it to output ['space'] when I press/hold space, which also did not happen. Instead I kept getting empty square brackets. The only times a character was output in the list was if function was pressed beforehand, such as in the case of function q which resulted in ['Super_L', 'q'] and then ['q'] if function is released but q is held.

Comment: The code seems to work for me on my mac. When I press and hold `q`, it appears in the output. Same with space and other keys. Are you running your code from a command prompt, or in some other way?

Comment: All I did was basically just open IDLE, open a new file, copy and paste, and then run.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with IDLE. Have you tried running the code from the command line?

Comment: When I said I was new with python, I was not kidding. What do you mean by running  the code from the command line?